# ImapX IndexOutOfRangeException on Message.Process()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, indexing, mailing

I've just started using your ImapX library to retrieve and read mails from gmail.
Now, everything is working fine and it's a great library.

However, when i'm trying to mark a mail read using the Message.Process() option, it returns the IndexOutOfRangeException.

```
private void Start()
    {
        int amountRead = 0;
        failedMessages.Clear();

        foreach(string origin Properties.Settings.Default.MailOrigins)
        {
            IMailOriginAdapter adapter = MailOriginFactory.CreateMailOriginContainer(origin);

            foreach (ImapX.Message message in adapter.Messages())
            {
                if (SendWebRequest(url))
                {
                    message.Process();
                    amountRead++;

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        this.btnStart.Content = &quot;Read [&quot; + amountRead + &quot;/&quot; + GmailUser.Instance.Messages.Count + &quot;]&quot;;
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    failedMessages.Add(message);
                }
            }

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(adapter.GmailFromEmail() + &quot; reading completed.&quot;);
        }
    }
```

Hopefully someone's capable of helping me with this problem which i've had now for over then a month..

Thanks in advance.

Yours Sincerely,
Larssy1

Comment: when you step thru the code.. which line throws the error..?

Comment: It's on the line of message.Process();

Comment: larssy1 do you or can you get a message count on this line `adapter.Messages()`